# Using Blade directives outside of templates

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Laravel 5.1: I defined a few custom directives inside a BladeServiceProvider (example below). Now I would like to use them outside of a view template to format strings (I am writing an EXCEL file with PHPExcel in a custom ExportService class). Is it possible to reuse my directives?

```
 Blade::directive('appFormatDate', function($expression) {
        return "<?php
         if (!is_null($expression)) {
           echo date(\Config::get('custom.dateformat'), strtotime($expression));
         }
         else {
           echo '-';
         }
         ?>";
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `BladeCompiler` has a `compileString` method, which allows you to use the Blade directives outside the views. :)

So, you can do things like this:

```
$timestamp = '2015-11-10 17:41:53';
$result = Blade::compileString('@appFormatDate($timestamp)');
```

Comment: hm, it seems that compileString returns a php function created from the custom method. :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;


$timestamp = '2023-01-28 12:41:53';
Blade::render("@appFormatDate({$timestamp})");
```